# Matlab: Read in ascii with varying column numbers & different formats

Tags: regex, matlab, ascii

I have been working on a puzzling question that involves reading an ascii file into matlab that contains 2 parts of different formats, the first part also including different column numbers.

```
MESH2D
MESHNAME "XXX"
E3T 1 1 29 30 1
E4Q 2 2 31 29 1 1
E4Q 3 31 2 3 32 1
...
...
...
ND 120450 5.28760039e+004 7.49260000e+004 8.05500000e+002
ND 120451 5.30560039e+004 7.49260000e+004 6.84126709e+002
ND 120452 5.32360039e+004 7.49260000e+004 6.97750000e+002
ND 120453 5.34010039e+004 7.49110000e+004 7.67000000e+002
NS  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
NS  11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
NS  21 22 23 24 25 26 27 -28
BEGPARAMDEF
GM  "Mesh"
```

I am only interested in the lines that contain the triangles and start with E3T/E4Q and the corresponding lines that hold the coordinates of the nodes of the triangles and start with ND. For the triangles (E3T/E4Q lines) I am only interest in the first 4 numbers, therefore I was trying to do something like this:

```
fileID = fopen(test);
t1 = textscan(fileID, '%s',3);
t2 = textscan(fileID, '%s %d %d %d*[^\n]');
fclose(fileID);
```

So read in the header to jump to the data and then read the first string and following 4 numbers, then jump to the end of the line and restart. But this does not work. I only get A single line with data and not the rest of the file. Also, I do not know how to treat the second part of the file, which starts at an arbitrary amount of numbers (which I could of course look up manually and feed into matlab, but would prefer matlab to find this change in format automatically).

Do you have any suggestions?

Cheers!

Comment: Seems like each line has a kind of header some numbers after it. Is it correct to assume amount of of numbers for each header string is always constant?

Comment: No, otherwise I would know how to do it. Each line has either 5 or 6 numbers following the "header" depending if its E3T or E4Q. In the ND part it is always "ND # X Y Z"

Comment: the dirty way: read line by line and use `regexp` to parse the lines...

Comment: I had regex in mind as well, that's why I tagged it here. But I cannot handle regex very well and was hoping for a cleaner solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not perfect, but if your files are not too big you can do something like this:

```
fileID = fopen(test,'r');
while ~feof(fileID)
    FileLine        = fgetl(fileID);
    [LineHead,Rem]  = strtok(FileLine);     % separated string header and numbers
    switch LineHead
        case 'MESH2D'
            % do something here
        case 'MESHNAME'
            % do something here
        case 'E3T'
            % parse integer numbers
            [Num,NumCount]  = sscanf(Rem, '%d');
        case 'E4Q'
            % parse integer numbers
            [Num,NumCount]  = sscanf(Rem, '%d');
        case 'ND'
            % parse integer numbers
            [Num,NumCount]  = sscanf(Rem, '%d');

            % or if you prefer to parse first number separately
            [strFirst,strOthers]    = strtok(Rem);
            FirstInteger            = str2num(strFirst);
            [Floats,FloatsCount]    = sscanf(strOthers, '%g');
        % and so on...
    end
end
fclose(fileID);
```

OF course, you have to handle strings starting with *MESH2D*, *MESHNAME*, or *GM* separately

Comment: Undefined function or variable 't'.
changed it to while(feof(fileID)), but still doesn't enter the loop. any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for typo, was thinking faster than typing. Se my updated answer.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Thanks a lot! It is a bit slow for large files though.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you first read all the lines of the file with `textscan` as strings, and then filter out whatever you need:

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '');
fclose(fid);
```

Then parse only the E3T/E4Q/ND lines using `regexp`:

```
C = regexp(C, '(\w*)(.*)', 'tokens');
C = cellfun(@(x){x{1}{1}, str2num(x{1}{2})}, C, 'UniformOutput', false);
C = vertcat(C{:});
```

And then group corresponding E3T/E4Q and ND lines:

```
idx1 = strcmp(C(:, 1), 'E3T') | strcmp(C(:, 1), 'E4Q');
idx2 = strcmp(C(:, 1), 'ND');
N = max(nnz(idx1), nnz(idx2));
indices = cellfun(@(x)x(1:4), C(idx1, 2), 'UniformOutput', false);
S = struct('tag', [C(idx1, 1); cell(N - nnz(idx1), 1)], ...
    'indices', [indices; cell(N - nnz(idx1), 1)], ...
    'nodes', [C(idx2, 2); cell(N - nnz(idx2), 1)]);
```

I named the E3T/E4Q values "indices" and ND values "nodes". The resulting array `S` contains structs, each having three fields: `tag` (either E3T or E4Q), `indices` and  `nodes`. Note that if you have more "indices" than "nodes" or vice versa, the missing values are indicated by an empty matrix.

Comment: Could you explain why you decided to *storing the first four numerical values from the E3T/E4Q line*?

Comment: @anandr It says so in the question: "_For the triangles (E3T/E4Q lines) I am only interest in the first 4 numbers_"

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I will check it out tomorrow. So far, anandr's solution works for me, although it is a bit slow.

Comment: @Eitan, Oh, I missed it, thanks. I can't guess which way will be faster, but personally I prefer your solution, as more "MatLab" style ;) +1

Comment: @Eitan thanks for your solution. I stick to anandr's solution though, as it is easier to understand for me at this point. I really have to get into regex and string parsing more. Thank you!